# Object.observe() useable with Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In my ideal world, I'd love for Polymer components to be able to use `Object.observe()` transparently to listen for changes to the properties of models, *without* the model objects having to themselves be custom elements.

In the example below, I have an element that has a property `model` of type `Object`. The HTML template uses `{{model.name}}` and I would like the element to update automatically whenever that property changes.

In my demo/example, the hacky way I accomplish this is by using `Object.observe()` within custom code, and when any change happens, I set `model` to `undefined` and back again. This "refreshes" the UI and picks up the changes. Of course, in any nontrivial UI, this would be very janky, so this is a bit of a "hope is not a strategy" moment....

Is there any design pattern for tersely doing this sort of thing right now, and/or a roadmap for doing such things in the future?

This is my custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="test-view">
  <template>
    <p>Hello, I am called <span>{{model.name}}</span>, how are you?</p>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'test-view',
    properties: {
      model: Object,
    },
    observers: [
      '_modelChanged(model)'
    ],
    ready: function() { },
    attached: function() { },
    detached: function() { },
    _modelChanged: function(model) {
      if (model) { Object.observe(model, this._observer.bind(this)); }
    },
    _observer: function() {
      const oldModel = this.model;
      this.model = undefined;
      this.model = oldModel;
    }
  });
</script>
```

and this is an HTML page that drives it through its state transitions:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../test-view/test-view.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <test-view id="first" model='{ "name": "Wilma" }'></test-view>
    <script>
      const newModel = { name: 'Fred' };
      const testView = document.querySelector('#first');
      window.setTimeout(function() { testView.model = newModel; }, 2000);
      window.setTimeout(function() { newModel.name = 'Barney'; }, 4000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a complete answer to your question, more of comment, but since code does not look well in comments I'm still posting it as an answer. I think that kind of thing may even have worked in 0.5 without the additional observer. However, to improve performance this kind of behaviour was removed in 1.0. I also hope we get it back sometime.

To avoid setting the model to undefined and back to trigger a refresh, you could also just notify Polymer of the changes. I assume that this would be more efficient, especially when you have complex objects and lots of data-binding.

```
_observer: function(changes) {
    changes.forEach(function(change){
        this.notifyPath("model." +change.name, change.object[change.name]);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Bloomin' brilliant, thank you! :) I'm a Polymer n00b so did not know about notifyPath.

Comment: Keep in mind that Object.observe only watches first-level properties of the element. If you have a deeper tree (e.g. model.name.first), the changes will not trigger an event.

Comment: Yeps, got that thank you! If I go deeper down the rathole that I seem self-destructively intent on traversing ;) then I need to add and remove observers to the entire model subtree of interest, and remember to unobserve() at the end of my element's lifecycle.

Fwiw/fyi, I ran into https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2225; watching to see what the Polymer folks say.